# Do I need to turn an HTMLCollection or a Nodelist to create an Array of nodes?

Tags: javascript, html, css

It,s the noob guy again. I doing this exercise from a book I am reading (Eloquent JavaScript). it,s suppose to work like "getElementByTagName". The first function below does not return anything. The second one can't get pass through the "if" statement after "while".

Thanks,

```js
function tagSearch (node, name) {

    let tagArrays = [];
    let childrenNode = node.childNodes;

    if(childrenNode.length != 0) {
        for(let i = 0; i < childrenNode.length; i++) {
            let currentNode = childrenNode[i];
            if(currentNode == Node.ELEMENT_NODE && currentNode.nodeName == name.toUpperCase()) {
                tagArrays.push(currentNode);
            }
            let child = tagSearch(currentNode, name )
            if(child) {
                tagArrays.concat(child);
            }
        }    
    }
    return tagArrays;
}
```

---

```js
function tagSearch (node, name) {

    let tagArrays = [];
    let currentNode = node.firstElementChild;

    while(currentNode != null) {
        if(currentNode.tagName == name.toUpperCase()) {
            tagArrays.push(currentNode);
        }
        let descendant = tagSearch(currentNode, name );
        if(descendant) {
            tagArrays.concat(descendant);
        }
        let currentNode = currentNode.nextElementSibling;
    }    
    return tagArrays;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You missed something in your condition. Here you're comparing node with expected node type:

```js
currentNode == Node.ELEMENT_NODE
```

You need to check node's type, not node itself:

```js
currentNode.nodeType == Node.ELEMENT_NODE
```

Also, this code is not doing anything:

```js
tagArrays.concat(child);
```

`concat()` function returns new array, not mutating old one. So, to add items to `tagArrays` you should do:

```js
tagArrays = tagArrays.concat(child);

or 

tagArrays.push(...child);

or

tagArrays.splice(tagArrays.length - 1, 0, child);
```

Comment: Thanks. That was embarrassing. But thanks again, I appreciate it.

Comment: if this answer is correct for you, you can mark it as right one with check icon for others to see

Answer (score 1):

You're currently comparing `currentNode` (a Node) to `Node.ELEMENT_NODE` (a number), which will always evaluate to `false`. You need to add the `nodeType` property to `currentNode` in your first `if` statement inside the for loop:

```js
function tagSearch (node, name) {

    let tagArrays = [];
    let childrenNode = node.childNodes;

    if(childrenNode.length != 0) {
        for(let i = 0; i < childrenNode.length; i++) {
            let currentNode = childrenNode[i];
            if(currentNode.nodeType == Node.ELEMENT_NODE && currentNode.nodeName == name.toUpperCase()) {
                tagArrays.push(currentNode);
            }
            let child = tagSearch(currentNode, name )
            if(child) {
                tagArrays.concat(child);
            }
        }    
    }
    return tagArrays;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. That was embarrassing. But thanks again, I appreciate it.